# All the transitions fail in safari

Tags: safari, css-transitions

It's the first time that I meet such a problem with transitions. 
None of them is working on Safari, although they work perfectly fine in firefox and chrome.

http://www.custom-design.ch/_stack/predentec/

I used compass transition mixins, as I always do, so there really shouldn't any problem.

Do you have any idea or track to follow?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I found the source of the problem, where it absolutely wasn't expected.

This was due to the new version of livereload (2.3.27), that makes apparently different results while exporting CSS code.

I then downgraded to v.2.3.20, and everything was ok, as it has always been!

I wrote to the support of both Livereload and compass to see where the problem comes, but without any answer for now.